# PSExec: How can I show a JPG file on a remote computer?

Tags: executable, psexec

I need to start a document on a remote computer instead of an executable file, using PSExec.

I tried to provide the file name of a jpg file to psexec associated with the -c command to copy the file, but the message returned for documents (and not executables) is always "The system cannot find the file specified."

Anyone any ideas what the command-line for psexec should be?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the command:

```
cmd.exe /c START c:\path\to\document.jpg
```

Document must be on the remote computer, so you have to copy it there by other command before calling psexec.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a program on that other machine that can show the JPEG and execute that, passing to it the path and name to the file you want to show.

As you've noticed, file associations doesn't work with remote execution like that, so you need to invoke the correct program instead.

Comment: I need the file to be copied to the remote machine. Since psexec copies the executable file instead of my document, how can I do this?

Comment: Copy it first, if you have remote execution access you should have write access as well.

Answer (score 1):

In order to open a remote program and not only activate its process you have to use PSEXEC 
with the -i (Interactive Mode) and MUST define the session number.

For example:

Usually on a Win7 host:

```
 Console = Session 0
 System = Session 1
 User = Session 2
```

In order to activate and open notepad.exe on this remote Win 7 host use the following syntax:

```
psexec -i 2 \\ComputerName -u User -p Pass notepad.exe
```

Regards,
Shai Ziv
shaix.ziv@intel.com

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that worked for me:

- I've logged on to the  via RDP:

  - I've copied a picture to the  to "C:\Users<MyUserName>\Pictures\smiley.png"
  - I've opened a new powershell-window, typed "tasklist" and found out my windows session id (I simple took the highest session id I've found)
- Back on my own PC:

  - I've downloaded PSTOOLS from https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip
  - I've unpacked PSTOOLS and placed it in "C:\Program Files\PSTools"
  - I've opened a new powershell-window and typed: cd "C:\Program Files\PSTools"
  - Finally i've started the remote PAINT with:

---

```
"C:\Program Files\PSTools\psexec" -s -i 4 "\\[RemoteComputerName]" "C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe" "C:\Users\[MyUserName]\Pictures\smiley.png"
```

---

P.S.: Don't forget to replace [RemoteComputerName] and [MyUserName]